# Protractor error : BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining for my simple first test

Tags: cucumber, protractor, bdd, ui-automation, chai

I run the below simple config/step and feature file for my first protractor test which is trying to recognize my feature file and console output.

I am getting the error BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining.

I am not sure what is going on here. Some help is appreciated.

### Feature file

```
Feature: Verify the Test Room Javascript application
Scenario: Check the input text field

Given I go to Test Run Application TC001
When I enter text on the Input field TC001
```

### Step file

```
module.exports = function (){
this.Given(/^I go to Test Run Application TC001$/, function(){

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get("https://www.thetestroom.com/jswebapp/");
    browser.sleep(8000);
            console.log("The testroom application opened");
        callback();
    });


    this.When(/^I enter text on the Input field TC001$/, function() {
                console.log("Trying to find the input field");

});
```

### and my config file:

```
exports.config = {
    chromeDriver: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    framework: 'cucumber',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['testrun.feature'],
  cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['testrun_steps.js'],
     }

}
```

I get the below error when I run the testrun_conf.js

Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

Feature: Verify the Test Room Javascript application

Scenario: Check the input text field              # testrun.feature:3
The testroom application opened
[launcher] BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using something like:

```js
this.AfterFeatures(function() {
  browser.close(); // not required
});
```